# MySql: Sum of two columns from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

It might be a **Repeated Question**, but my problem is not solving.

I am trying to determine the Inward and Outward of Item using Date

tables.

In table 1, We will call it `A` for short. I would have three columns
   namely `A_Dt`, `A_Na`, `A_Qty`

In table 2, We will call it 'B' for short. I would have three columns namely `B_Dt`, `B_N`a,`B_Qty`

In table 3, We will call it 'C' for short. I would
   have three columns    namely `C_Dt`, `C_N`a, `C_Qty`

Table A and B are inward and  C are outward.

I had used the revised query but adding the Third column.

Table Example:

```
Table :A

    A_Dt         A_Na  A_Qty
    2016-08-01    XY     50
    2016-08-02    XY     100
    2016-08-05    XY     150
```

Table B:

```
B_Dt       B_Na  B_Qty
2016-08-01  XY  150
2016-08-03  XY  100
2016-08-04  XY  200
```

Table C:

```
C_Dt       C_Na  C_Qty
2016-08-01  XY  150
2016-08-03  XY  100
2016-08-04  XY  200
```

Expected Output

```
Date           Inward   Outward
2016-08-01      200      150
2016-08-02      100      0
2016-08-03      100      100
2016-08-04      200      200
2016-08-05      150      0
```

Well, in this case I should use left join or following query must be worked.

Query:

```
select t.Dt as Date, sum(t.Qty) as Inward,sum(t.outward) as outward1 from(
    select A_Dt as Dt, A_Na as Na, A_Qty as Qty from a
    union all
    select B_Dt as Dt, B_Na as Na, B_Qty as Qty from b
    union all
    select C_Dt as Dt, C_Na as Na, C_Qty as outward from c
)t
group by t.Dt, t.Na
order by t.Dt;
```

Following Error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 't.outward' in 'field list'
```

Any thoughts would be great.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at UNION?

Answer (score 4):

First combine both the table data into one by using `union all` and then find the sum of quantity group by date and Na columns.

**Query**

```
select t.Dt, t.Na as Inward, sum(t.Qty) as Outward from(
    select A_Dt as Dt, A_Na as Na, A_Qty as Qty from Table_A
    union all
    select B_Dt as Dt, B_Na as Na, B_Qty as Qty from Table_B
)t
group by t.Dt, t.Na
order by t.Dt;
```

**EDIT**

Actually now don't need to combine data of TableC, but you have to use a join.

**Query**

```
select t1.Dt, t1.Qty as Inward, coalesce(t2.C_Qty, 0) as Outward from(
    select t.Dt, t.Na, sum(t.Qty) as Qty from(
        select A_Dt as Dt, A_Na as Na, A_Qty as Qty from Table_A
        union all
        select B_Dt as Dt, B_Na as Na, B_Qty as Qty from Table_B
    )t
    group by t.Dt, t.Na
)t1
left join Table_C t2
on t1.Dt = t2.C_Dt
order by 1;
```

**Result**

```
+============+========+=========+
| Dt         | Inward | Outward |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 2016-08-01 | 200    | 150     |
| 2016-08-02 | 100    | 0       |
| 2016-08-03 | 100    | 100     |
| 2016-08-04 | 200    | 200     |
| 2016-08-05 | 150    | 0       |
+============+========+=========+
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. But Now I edited the Query.I need Another Output.Any suggestions for that.

Comment: No, there is some misunderstanding. I need a Inward for  aliases 'Qty' and Outward for Aliases 'Outward'. Please refer the Expected Output. You will get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs only a small correction

```
select t.Dt as Date, sum(t.Qty) as Inward, sum(t.outward) as outward1 from(
   select A_Dt as Dt, A_Na as Na, A_Qty as Qty, 0 as outward from a
   union all
   select B_Dt as Dt, B_Na as Na, B_Qty as Qty, 0 as outward from b
   union all
   select C_Dt as Dt, C_Na as Na, 0 as Qty, C_Qty as outward from c
)t
-- where Na = 'XY'
group by t.Dt, t.Na
order by t.Dt;
```